# Index signature of type 'string' on interface not recognized (typescript)

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this code:

```
const sectionInstance: FieldValues = sectionInstances[i]
for (const field in sectionInstance) {
    console.log(sectionInstance[field])
}
```

`field` here is of course a string. Here is the type definition for `FieldValues`:

```
export interface FieldValues = {
  [key: string]: FieldValue;
}
```

Still I get this error:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type
> 'string' can't be used to index type 'FieldValues'.   No index
> signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type
> 'FieldValues'.Vetur(7053)

Haven't I declared an index signature of type 'string' for `interface FieldValues`? Why do I get this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove `=` from interface definition.

[Please take a look at playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglhANgEwGoENEFdoF4oDeAvgNwCwAUJXAHbAQBOAZugMbTxJqY4DOhlKFADaAawggAXFF7AGtAOYBdaZxQZsEchSKVKrAPY1ZMiK2BwjASWPB0Ndr1UJ1PCL2FKo+TySj6jE14zC2tbe3ZnLg0+b1NzSxobWQj3YQAGJW0mAwYoAApDWygmF2QoWnjQpPCHCABKAQohIt4DRAgAOkQDBXzghLCUuuFSriV67SIgA)

```
interface FieldValues {
  [key: string]: FieldValue;
}
...
const sectionInstance: FieldValues = sectionInstances[i];
for (const field in sectionInstance) {
  console.log(sectionInstance[field]);
}
```

Comment: Also, according to generic coding rules, it is not a good idea to have plural names of types

Comment: "*Please take a look at playground*" - why? What's there? What does the linked playground code demonstrate? Please state that in your answer.

Comment: Just remove `=` from interface definition:

Comment: What's the alternative to have plural name of this type?

Comment: For example, `FieldValueMap`.It mostly about distance between plural and singular form.
I mean `FieldValue` vs `FieldValues`
and `FieldValue` vs `FieldValueMap`

Answer (score 0):

As I know, Typescript can not infer the key type from `[key: string]`. it's only useful when you are trying to generalize that some keys(probably except the others) might be there with string type. TS cannot ensure that the key you are accessing in the `for` is of the type `string` you used in `[key: string]`. you should say it explicitly.